# Unicode font changes depending on input in text box

Tags: font, keynote, unicode

The letter ℂ, which is unicode U+2102 behaves strangely in Keynote. If presented by itself in a text box, one font is displayed. However, if it is prepended with the letter , which is unicode U+1D53B, a different font is used. I'd like the fonts for all double struck characters to be the same, but I'm finding it impossible to get ℂ by itself in the same font as . How can this be done?

The screenshot below shows this phenomenon in Keynote. The font has not been changed to get from the first rendering of ℂ to its rendering in ℂ. Deleting the  makes the font of ℂ revert back to the first one.

[image: C and DC]

Comment: After some digging around, a partial answer is that OS X uses a fallback font list to determine the fonts that are to be used. In my case, I'm happy with Cambria Math, which provides the fonts in the bottom of the screenshot. That still doesn't explain why the fallback changes depending on the text that is present...

Comment: Could it be because the font for the first C does not include the character for the D?  The first is in the basic multilingual plane of Unicode, while the D is from one of the higher planes, which are supported by far fewer fonts.

Comment: Yes, I think it'll be something like that. I would have imagined that once a fallback for a letter is found, then that font is used. Seems like it's more complex than that.

Comment: Open Fontbook, select your font and then go to View → Repertorie. There you can check if exists character D for that font.

Comment: Yes, I would have expected you to have the characters in two different fonts. For keynote to insist on using a font which contains both is a lot smarter than that.

Comment: I've noticed this happening in the Notes app for a handful of unicode characters. ℬ vs ℬ is another example. Some arrow characters also do this.